# Update value in sql through Id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page wherein I need to update the record in $result. This will be updated when username already exists in database. But I can't get the ID of the record in $result.

below is my tried code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM logcalls WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' LIMIT 1");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){

    $upd = "UPDATE logcalls SET totalcall = totalcall + 1 AND problem = '$_POST[problem]' AND dateinput = '$_POST[dateinput]' where id = '$_POST[id]'";
    mysqli_query($con, $upd);
    header('location: registration.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You schould use `$result_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM logcalls WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' LIMIT 1");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
  $result_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $upd = "UPDATE logcalls SET totalcall = totalcall + 1 AND problem = '".$_POST['problem']."' AND dateinput = '".$_POST['dateinput']."' WHERE id = '".$result_data['id']."'";
  mysqli_query($con, $upd);
  header('location: registration.php');
}
```

Or maybe `WHERE firstname='".$firstname."'` in your `UPDATE`